# Why did Ubuntu fail, given that the installation was successful?

Tags: installation

I just tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 on my new laptop, dual-booting alongside windows 8, i burnt the iso to a CD-R and installed it. The installation went fine, I got up to the part where it told me to take the disk out and press enter to restart my PC. But now when it has started, it simply says "repairing disk errors. this might take over an hour to complete." I followed the installation instructions exactly, and yet I know cannot access my laptop. Can anyone give me some idea of how to repair this.

Just in case it is helpful, the laptops specs are 8G ram, AMD 10 Quad Core processor, 750G Hard Drive.

Comment: Where and when does it say "repairing disk errors"?

Comment: Just after I power on the laptop. There is the HP icon, underneath that it says "repairing disk errors."

Answer (score 1):

"repairing disk errors" does not mean the installation failed, it means on startup,  there are problems with your HDD.

Just let it run the repair which may take a while and then it should boot.

Comment: Okay, thanks :) , I will wait it out for the night, and if need be, for the rest of the day tomorrow. I was just worried that I had ruined a brand new laptop. Ill come back if there are any other problems.

Comment: Hmm, i waited it out, and that stopped. But now when i boot i just get a black screen. I have tried booting again from the live CD i used to install, is there anyway I can remove Ubuntu from within that?

Comment: Okay then it sounds like Grub did not properly configure itself.  You can just run a reinstall of Ubuntu using the live CD, it will give you the option as you run through the install wizard when it gets to partitioning.  Grub will probably install properly the second time.